# How do I raise my Link Speed (receive/transmit)?

Tags: networking, windows-10, ethernet

I just changed my ISP to frontier and got 200/200 speeds but my gaming PC only reads 100/100 when I viewed my network properties.(Yes I'm connected through Ethernet) I was wondering how I would go about changing that because when I do speed test, I get 95 down 98 up (Ethernet). When I do the speed test on my phone, I get 199 download and 196 upload (WiFi) I've googled just about everything and tried everything I've read.

Comment: What is your gaming PC connected to? What kind of cable are you using? What kind of network interface? One of those three things is not gigabit capable, but there's no way we can know which.

Comment: I feel like it might be my ethernet cable. thats the only thing i kept from my old internet.                                                                                                      
Name: Ethernet
Description: Intel(R) Ethernet Connection (2) I219-V

Status: Operational
Maximum transmission unit: 1500
Link speed (Receive/Transmit): 100/100 (Mbps)

Comment: This is some of the stuff it shows when i view my network properties.

Comment: You need at least a cat 5E cable (the e is important) - check what's written on yours.

Comment: @djsmiley2k 1000BASE-T was designed and specified for up to 100m of plain old Cat5. You just have to be sure to have all 4 pairs (8 conductors) properly terminated.

Answer (score 1):

It is most likely your ethernet cable, if your ethernet cable is a cat5 cable, max speed you can get is 100mbps. I would recommend switching to a cat 5e or preferably a cat 6 ethernet cable. I checked the ethernet port you provided and you are capable of 1gig speeds, try a network cable and that should fix the issue.

Comment: It was the cable! I switched it to a cat 5e cable im it's giving me higher speeds now and the link speed went up to 1000/1000.

Comment: @hxteDeity Good deal that it was a simple fix.

Comment: "if your ethernet cable is a cat5 cable, max speed you can get is 100mbps" - no. A Cat5 cable is able to run at gigabit speed *but you need to have four full pairs* for 1000BASE-T.

Comment: 1000BASE-T (gigabit Ethernet) was designed, specified, and tested to run on up to 100m of plain old Cat 5 cable. If switching out his cable fixed the problem, it was almost certainly because his old cable didn't have all 4 pairs properly terminated, not an issue with the quality of the copper.

Comment: @Mammolytic always pleasure to see a issue resolves.

Comment: @HxtedDeity If this solved your issue [accept this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/1041018).